# Adjusting subplot layout with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I came to realize that **matplotlib**'s `tight_layout()` cannot be applied to plots generated by **pandas**.

This is the code I am running:

```
            0         1         2         3         4
A    0.039895  0.960105       NaN       NaN       NaN
D    0.030418  0.969582       NaN       NaN       NaN
E    0.037345  0.962655       NaN       NaN       NaN
F    0.061522  0.938478       NaN       NaN       NaN
G    0.047163  0.952837       NaN       NaN       NaN
H    0.026423  0.000000  0.000000  0.973577       NaN

df.T.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, width=0.7, legend=False, 
                             layout=(2,4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I end up with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_bbox'
```

I also believe that this is related to a similar issue posted on github:
 [DataFrame.hist() does not get along with matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout() #9351](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9351%22https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9351)

Therefore, I am looking for a workaround based on `subplots_adjust(*args, **kwargs)`. Most importantly, I was trying to adjust the `hspace` parameter. However, these keyword arguments are not accepted when calling the `plot` function of **pandas**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code that produced the error. Namely, how you called plt. If you don't have any sublots (even if its only one), you can't call the subplots_adjust() method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `tight_layout()` definitely works with pandas!

***without `tight_layout()`***

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, width=0.7, legend=False, 
                             layout=(3, 2), sharex=True, sharey=True)
# plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

***with `tight_layout()`***

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, width=0.7, legend=False, 
                             layout=(3, 2), sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: even if I just copy your code using python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.0 with Spyder on a Mac, I get the same error as stated above.

Comment: @Fourier interesting!  must be a version issue.  I'm using python 3.5 and pandas 0.19.  I'll check again with different version.

Comment: Okay if you want to close this question, please go ahead. I am sorry, I found the problem. I have a figure layout that contains more subplots than will be used for plotting and pandas removes them automatically. When using tight_layout() with this I get the error stated above. However, when using only a layout matrix that fits the number of plots exactly it will work!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by piRSquared pointed out `tight_layout()` definitely works. However, the layout should be exactly agreeing with the number of subplots.

Pandas automatically removes empty subplots and thus figure layouts with more than the required number of subplots will cause the error stated above.

Here is my own solution to the problem. As simple as it gets.

Using `plt.subplots_adjust()` one can easily adjust the required parameters after plotting the figure.